# Is FirebaseAuth # signInWithCredential result internally cached (for some period) or it performs a network trip & reauthetnicates on each invocation?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

The previous version of Firebase (before google-fication) had an API **`Firebase#getAuth()`** which would return non-null if there was a currently logged in user allowing us to short-circuit authentication. That was spelled out in the docs and clients were encouraged to use it for performance.

Is the new **`FirebaseAuth#signInWithCredential`** API intended to not perform a full re-authentication if the user has recently authenticated, or clients of the library need to keep track of that themselves and only invoke when necessary? I couldn't find any details in the official [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#signInWithCredential(com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential)) or in the [guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin).

Basically, what is the contract of the method? Is it designed for use where I can invoke it multiple times and it returns immediately the successful authenticated state after a first full authentication (up to some expiry period), or does it perform a full-blown network-based authentication every single time?

Comment: I think you are describing a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Give us your real problem.

Comment: you were right in that you could say my question was: "what is the equivalent to the old Firebase#getAuth() so i can avoid unnecessary authentication trips" though i still wanted to really know if signInWithCredential result is internally cached for some period. Frank didn't quite reply to the latter, he basically said what was in the docs which leaves the question open, but the rest of his answer helps me. So XY perhaps, but more like those could be split into two separate questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if a user is signed in, call `FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()`. It is the equivalent of `Firebase.getAuth()` in the 2.x SDK.

Calling `FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential()` will try to sign in with the credentials you specify.

If you want to know when a user gets signed in/signed out or something changes about their state, use `FirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener()`.

Comment: thanks, this does answer the hidden XY problem in my question, so i've marked it as accepted and upvoted, but your answer still doesn't actually address my explicit question, you just spelled out what's already in the docs. I was more interested in whether the API has internal expiry or not, or even if that behavior is unspecified by design